# Symfony2 demo testing issues

Tags: testing, symfony, phpunit, symfony-2.2

I just installed the last version of phpunit and when I run the demo test with:

```
bin/phpunit src/Acme/DemoBundle/Tests/
```

I get this problems:

```
1) Acme\DemoBundle\Tests\Controller\DemoControllerTest::testIndex
RuntimeException: Unable to guess the Kernel directory.
```

and the lines where the kernel is citated

Any ideas about why does this DEMO TEST doesn't works?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try runing `bin/phpunit -c app/ src/Acme/DemoBundle/Tests/` from your project root directory.

There is `app/phpunit.xml.dist` phpunit configuration file, setting some options needed by Symfony.